# What does 流れ mean here? - 「その流れ 気に入ってるのですか？」

Tags: meaning, words, nuances

In the anime Quintessential Quintuplets, the mc 風太郎 is walking home with the quint girls. When the quints are curious about his test results, he is hesitant to give it to them, but in reality he wants them to see since he got max score, and he has done this with them in the past a few times already. The conversation goes like this:

> （四葉）えっ ぜ… 全部１００点！
> （風太郎）あ～ めっちゃ恥ずかしい 
> （五月）その流れ 気に入ってるのですか？

This was translated as the following: “Are you trying to make that your thing?”

When I checked the dictionary, none of the meanings explain 流れ being used this way. But I did recently stumble upon the word 一流 which means:

> 他とは違う独特の流儀

Which has a meaning that would make sense in this situation. Am I correct in thinking that 流れ is being used in this sense, or is this a different kind of meaning?

Comment: 一流 almost always means "first-class; top-ranking" in modern Japanese. You can probably forget this definition of 他とは違う独特の流儀.

Answer (score 2):

The 流れ means something like *fixed sequence*. In this case, I suppose there were exchanges similar to えっ ぜ… 全部１００点！→あ～ めっちゃ恥ずかしい previously in the story.

その流れ refers to this exchange between 四葉 and 風太郎 (most probably it's between those two, but at least one must be 風太郎). So その流れ気に入ってるのですか？ means more literally *Do you guys love the exchange fixed into a pattern?*, and the translation in the sub tries to convey the meaning ('Oh again, you guys like that, will you do that again?').

---

A more common phrase is 話の流れ, which means *the course of the story*.

Comment: Considering the dictionary meanings, would「時の経過や時間に伴う物事の移り変わり。続き具合。「歴史の―」「会議の―」「試合の―が変わる」」 be the one to apply here?

Comment: Technically, the pattern you just mentioned could be considered an event brought about by the passage of time and events? Basically, a sequence as you mentioned, right?

Comment: @Mernn1 Yes. I think it is close to some use of *course*, like course of events.